# DEPRECATION `RSolr.escape` is deprecated (and incorrect). Use `Rsolr.solr_escape` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

**Project environment**

- Ruby 1.9.3p392
- Rails 3.1.12
- gem 'sunspot_rails' , '2.0.0'
- gem 'sunspot_solr' , '2.0.0'

  [DEPRECATION] `RSolr.escape` is deprecated (and incorrect).  Use `Rsolr.solr_escape` instead.

How can I fix this warning, anyone have same issue?? and found solution?

Comment: Did you try using `Rsolr.solr_escape`, as suggested in the error message?

Comment: You mean to say, I have to change this line in Gem files?

Comment: This a typical example of some functions becoming deprecated in the newer version of a language. What you should do is search for appearances of function `RSolr.escape` in your code and replace them with calls to function `Rsolr.solr_escape`.

Comment: I update the gems and fix for me

Answer (score 0):

you can remove this line:

```
rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/char.rb: warn "[DEPRECATION] RSolr.escape is deprecated (and incorrect).  Use RSolr.solr_escape instead."
```